# Ember.JS do an operation every time the JSON is loaded

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I am new to Ember and in my APP I need to add some operations depending on the JSON I get from the server.

This is currently my logic:

In the component.js

```
var foo = [];

didInsertElement() {
  var data  = this.get('content');
  //then I do some transformations with data to obtain what I want and assign it to foo

  data.forEach(function(option) {
    list.push( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(option)))
  })

  for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    //some logic code with list
  }

  this.set('foo', someTransformationFromList);


  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    this.get('content').push(jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.get('content')[0]));
  }

  for(i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    this.get('content')[i].set('string1', foo[i].text);            
    this.get('content')[i].set('id', foo[i].value);
  }
}
```

So now the question is, I need to move this logic from didInsertElement to somewhere else so it gets executed every time I get my JSON no just the first time when the component is rendered.  I have tried to use a serializer or a transform but I don't know if I can use any of them. Can you please give me any pointers about how to do this task?.

Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right way. Could you provide us bit more information about what exactly do you want to transform? Is it a complex JSON object or is it just a formatting issue (for example date or currency formatting)?

Comment: Maybe just a computed property?

Comment: In my case I don't think a computed property will do the trick because I even need to add stuff into this.get('content'')

Comment: @Peyu I don't see why this should be a limitation. Do you use ember-data?

Comment: @Lux Thanks for the answer yes I am using Ember Data

Comment: I'm not quite sure if a computed property named `id` is possible. But `string1` should be just fine as a computed property on content elements. On the other hand you should not use `didInsertElement` but an observer on `content.@each.your-property-name`. your-property-name depends on what properties are used for element text and value.

Comment: @jelhan can you provide this option in an answer with more details about how to implement it?.Thank you.

Comment: @Peyu could you please provide more information about `content` and why one property is named `id`? Perhaps the component template would be also helpfull.

Comment: @jelhan please see http://collabedit.com/wxy53 for the JSON of content plus the complete code. So I am adding some data to the content and then I am overwritting it, in the last for. Hope is more clear with the code now.

Comment: Hello! Wrangling JSON in `didInsertElement` seems a bad idea. If you use a component you should at least put it into `init()` function as it has nothing to do with the DOM as i see and `didInsertElement` is used to hook up some code which needs to execute when the component is already rendered so you get access to your DOM. The other important aspect is that if you use ember-data then the JSON wrangling code should be put inside adapter if you need raw json manipulations. If these manipulations are dependent on something else in the app you can put this code inside your model using `computed`

Comment: @Peyu link is not working.

Comment: @jelhan Hi Jelhan, thanks for your comment, please check the link again. I removed the code after a few hours